# Date { NaN } React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, timestamp

I'm using react native and I'm trying to convert my timestamp data to date but the output said "Date { NaN }"

```
       const [eventData1, setEventData1] = useState({});
        
          useEffect(() => {
            database()
              .ref('path')
              .on('value', snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
                  setEventData1({...snapshot.val()});
                } else {
                  setEventData1({});
                }
              });
        
            return () => {
              setEventData1([]);
            };
          }, []);
    
     const dates = Object.keys(eventData1).map(
        id => eventData1[id].start_DATE * 1000,
      );
      const sDate = new Date(dates);
```

Outputs

```
    console.log(dates) -----> //[1648703685000, 1648623600000]//
    
    console.log(sDate) ------> //Date { NaN }//
```

Comment: I revised my post. It's console.log(dates) instead of console.log(eventData1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dates` is an array of UNIX timestamps `[1648703685000, 1648623600000]` which you are trying to pass to the `Date()` constructor. But `Date()` does not take an array but can take a single timestamp as a parameter. You will have to loop over the dates to get the start and (presumably) end date parsed.

```js
const dates = [1648703685000, 1648623600000]
const parsedDates = dates.map(date => new Date(date));
const [startD, endD] = parsedDates;

console.log("Start:", startD);
console.log("End:", endD);
```

BTW: You can do the above in one line if you want to:

```js
const [startD, endD] = dates.map(date => new Date(date));
```